# Why are Python scripts quitting unexpectedly on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 PC which has recently developed the following interesting problem. I write a lot of Python code and long-running scripts have recently started quitting for, as far as I can tell, no reason.

As an example, I can start my Django-based webpage with `python manage.py runserver` and it will occasionally load in the browser, but as soon as I try to do anything with it, the script will stop without any kind of exit code or error message. This same script was running fine until recently and I do not know what might have changed.

It might be related to the number of programs I have running - they tend to die more quickly when multiple windows are open - but as the CPU usage and memory are consistently under 50% utilised, I can't imagine why this would be a problem.

I've tried running my code in debug mode, but as the code struggles to start and as this affects multiple scripts using multiple packages, often with no overlap of imports or code, I'm rather at a loss with what to try next. It only seems to affect Python-related scripts, although most of my work is Python. I'm leaning towards this being a Windows issue rather than a Python one given that the same code is running fine on other systems.

I'm using Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10.

Example display from Django code:

```py
(venv) C:\Users\User\mydjangocode>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 05, 2020 - 11:54:02
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'mycode.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

(venv) C:\Users\User\mydjangocode>
```

There was around a five minute period after the line `Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.` was displayed before I tried to visit `127.0.0.1:8000`. The script quit almost instantly as soon as I tried to load the page.

EDIT:

I've tried changing to a non-venv version of Python, with no effect.

I've checked Windows Event Viewer and there are a lot of recent error messages in there.

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.150.1013, time stamp: 0x5b331a30
Faulting module name: python37.dll, version: 3.7.150.1013, time stamp: 0x5b3319ec
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002a8fb
Faulting process ID: 0x4e0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5c3c171203e29
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Python37\python37.dll
Report ID: 164a49d4-38e6-41e9-9cfa-3fa2b0a99bed
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've also tried upgrading to Python 3.8 with no effect.

EDIT2:

I've run the system file check utility which didn't highlight any issues:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

I've also run CHKDSK which hasn't highlighted anything.

Comment: Maybe check the Event Viewer, if that is still a thing in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like a good starting point and it's filled with recent errors!

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.150.1013, time stamp: 0x5b331a30
Faulting module name: python37.dll, version: 3.7.150.1013, time stamp: 0x5b3319ec
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002a8fb
Faulting process ID: 0x4e0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5c3c171203e29
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Python37\python37.dll
Report ID: 164a49d4-38e6-41e9-9cfa-3fa2b0a99bed
```

Comment: You're getting an access violation in the main interpreter DLL, which can stem from various causes -- but is likely a buggy extension/ctypes module. Switch to running the debug build (python_d.exe), which has assertions enabled. The problem may be caught by a failed assertion. Otherwise you need an analysis under a debugger, preferably with page heap enabled (i.e. break into the debugger immediately on most heap errors).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where can I find python_d.exe? It doesn't seem to be with python.exe.

Comment: When installing Python, enable the options to install the debug binaries and symbols. You should also be able to modify an existing installation to get them.

Comment: Run the non-venv using **python -m pdb manage.py runserver**.  This will drop you into the debugger and you can debug it from there.

Comment: I'm missing VCRUNTIME140D.dll. I'm downloading some of the Visual Studio tools from Microsoft now...

Comment: I've tried running my code with 3.8 too with the same effect.

Comment: Do you have any other server applications running on that port (8000), which could be conflicting? Try a different port.

Comment: No, nothing else is running. And I've just restarted so there shouldn't be anything unexpected going on in the background

Comment: An access violation (status code 0xC0000005) is a serious, low-level programming error (e.g. double free; writing to an invalid address; writing to read-only executable memory; overwriting heap structures due to a buffer overrun; trashing the stack; etc). It's not a matter access in terms of shared resources or file security. And it's not a high-level programming error at the Python level that can be inspected with pdb, but pdb can be used in tandem with a platform debugger such as WinDbg.